# Defining BASH function for c++ compile

Tags: bash

I'd like to create a bash function like this:

```
acmcom source.cpp output
```

It's supposed to do the same thing as:

```
g++ -g -O2 -std=gnu++14 -static source.cpp -o output
```

But I couldn't find anything on how to do this in Ubuntu using bashscr file. How can I define this function for further usages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define a function, you can add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
acmcom(){
    echo g++ -g -O2 -std=gnu++14 -static "$1" -o "$2" > acmcom
}
```

Save the file, open a new terminal and you can now run:

```
acmcom  source.cpp output
```

Comment: Well what I wanted came with some small changes:
        acmcom() { g++ -g -O2 -std=gnu++14 -static "$1" -o "$2" }
I didn't want it echoed. I needed it to be executed. But thanks :)